# Redis::TimeoutError: Connection timed out Error -Rails cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, amazon-elasticache

We are using redis(Elasticache) as our cache store.We are experiencing crashes in our app due to redis connection timeout.We have three app servers and use phusion passenger.At the time of crashes there are about 200 active connections.

```
/home/chillr/deploy/chillr-api/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:55:in `rescue in _read_from_socket'
/home/chillr/deploy/chillr-api/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:48:in `_read_from_socket'
/home/chillr/deploy/chillr-api/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:41:in `gets'
/home/chillr/deploy/chillr-api/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:273:in `read'
/home/chillr/deploy/chillr-api/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/client.rb:248:in `block in read'
/home/chillr/deploy/chillr-api/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/client.rb:236:in `io'
/home/chillr/deploy/chillr-api/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/client.rb:247:in `read'
/home/chillr/deploy/chillr-api/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/client.rb:112:in `block in call'
/home/chillr/deploy/chillr-api/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/client.rb:217:in `block (2 levels) in process'
/home/chillr/deploy/chillr-api/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/client.rb:353:in `ensure_connected'
/home/chillr/deploy/chillr-api/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/client.rb:207:in `block in process'
/home/chillr/deploy/chillr-api/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/client.rb:292:in `logging'
/home/chillr/deploy/chillr-api/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/client.rb:206:in `process'
/home/chillr/deploy/chillr-api/shared/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/client.rb:112:in `call'
```

SlOWLOG commands

```
1) 1) (integer) 6867375
2) (integer) 1486701507
3) (integer) 62008
4) 1) "eval"
   2) "for i, name in ipairs(redis.call('KEYS', 'cache:user_transaction_logs:*:9008245678')) do redis.call('DEL', name); end"
   3) "0"
 2) 1) (integer) 6867374
    2) (integer) 1486701507
    3) (integer) 61989
    4) 1) "KEYS"
       2) "cache:user_transaction_logs:*:9008245678"
 3) 1) (integer) 6867373
    2) (integer) 1486701507
    3) (integer) 61026
    4) 1) "eval"
       2) "for i, name in ipairs(redis.call('KEYS', 'cache:user_transaction_logs:*:8888662136')) do redis.call('DEL', name); end"
       3) "0"
 4) 1) (integer) 6867372
    2) (integer) 1486701507
    3) (integer) 61006
    4) 1) "KEYS"
       2) "cache:user_transaction_logs:*:8888662136"
 5) 1) (integer) 6867371
    2) (integer) 1486701507
    3) (integer) 63070
    4) 1) "eval"
```

We use

- Elasticache cache.
- t2.medium Phusion Passenger

No of connections at time of Crash 175..200

GEM
   redis (3.2.1)
   redis-rails (5.0.1)

What could be done

Comment: Don't use keys in production: https://redis.io/commands/keys

Comment: But We cannot Avoid It in this case.We want to fetch the all transactions of a user from cache.Any alternatives

Comment: You could try scan, or change the structure of your data so you can look up the users transactions directly, like using a set that links user id's to transaction id's

Answer (score 0):

Monitor current resource usage for your redis server.
Temporally increase your connection timeout redis connection.

Try this check list first

https://redis.io/topics/latency

Comment: We have upgraded our elasticache server.Waiting too see